# Google Sheets: "If item is "out of stock", then remove item from data validation list

Tags: javascript, excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am have been trying to find a solution to my google sheet issue and have tried quite a few workarounds thus far, to no avail. I imagine I may need to use javascript to do the action, however, I am a beginner to javascript.

Here is what I would like the sheet to do.

1. Check 'sheet#2' and see if an item in the specified range is set to "out-of-stock"

**Sheet#2**

[image]

2. If the item in the range is set to "out-of-stock", then remove the item from the data validation list on 'sheet#1' and if it is "in-stock" then show the item on the data validation list.

**Sheet#1**

[image]

---

Here are some things I have tried thus far (if it helps):

1. on sheet#2 when an item is set to out stock, conditional format it, to make the cell text white (not visible). This works well for that particular sheet. however, data validation lists do not display the data it pulls exactly as it appears (so the text still shows on the dropdown list)
2. IF statement. I've tried a WHOLE LOTTA IF and IFS statements. This did not work, because you cannot have an if statement in the same cell as a data validation cell and b/c the cell name will likely need to be constantly changed in the future. (But I did, however, find a workaround to another issue I was trying to solve for a day now WHOOP WHOOP!)
3. Oh and I also tried conditional formating the cell so that if it ='s out of stock white out the cell... however I get an error that conditional formatting does not work across 2 sheets

... so yeah if anyone may know of a solution to get this to work I will forever appreciate it! I'll keep scouring google for solutions in the meantime.

Comment: can you please include the if statements you have tried? It sounds like you need to rethink the sheet. You should not need Javascript to do this, and congrats on working out another problem in the process :)

Comment: hmm I have been trying for a couple of hours now, so alot of them I removed for not working. But 1 that I tried was on sheet#2: 

IF(I3="out-of-stock",  "")  ... however, when set back to in-stock the item name is no longer there.

And the other on sheet#1:

IF(sheet#2!I3="in-stock), J3=sheet#2H3) however this didnt work for me with a list of titems

Comment: Cool, so what makes something out of stock? Also, take a look at https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2017/07/05/vlookup-google-sheets-example/ and then filter the column so it only displays values that are not False for example.

Comment: hmmm.. so I've been reading on the link you sent 'VLookup'  have not figured anything thus far, but I will continue trying... and for this particular sheet a item is  "out of stock" if the user selects out-of-stock from a drop down list

Comment: Yeah take a look at vlookups, maybe even watch a tutorial on youtube. They are amazing and will save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of simplicity, I've created a sample spreadsheet with two sheets: Sheet 1 and "Stock".

**Sheet 1**

[image: Sheet 1]

**Stock**

[image: Stock]

## Solution

I've created an Apps Script function to set the Data Validation as you have specified.

I've used the Javascript [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) functions to simplify getting the data, but basically:

1. I get all the rows from the Stock sheet and load them into "memory"
2. I then discard from "memory" the rows that do not have their second column (`row[1]`) equal to "In Stock".
3. Then I get the remaining rows and grab only their first column (`row[0]`).

I then create a new [DataValidation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation) object (with it's [builder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder)) that uses the list we got above and assign it to the range I want to have validated.

```
//VARIABLES
  var rangeToValidate = "B2:B";
  var validateSheet = "Sheet1";
  var optionSheet = "Stock";

function refreshDataValidation() {
  
  var inStockOptions = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(optionSheet).getDataRange().getValues()
  .filter(function (row) { return (row[1]=="In Stock")})
  .map(function(row) {return row[0]});
  
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(validateSheet).getRange(rangeToValidate)
  .setDataValidation(
    SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(inStockOptions).build()
  );
  
}
```

Also, by adding some code with Apps Script, the sheet will make sure that your drop-down is always up-to-date.

I am refreshing the drop-down every time the sheet is opened and every time there is an edit to the Stock sheet on the B column.

```
//When the sheet is opened, refresh the data validation
function onOpen(e) {
  refreshDataValidation();
}

//When a change is made to the Stock sheet, also refresh validation
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  if (range.getSheet() == SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(optionSheet) && range.getColumn() == 2) {
    refreshDataValidation();
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi ZektorH! Thanks for the code, I have been playing around with it since last night, I am able to get it to work partially. One thing I have been confused about is how do I define what range of data it should make the dropdown list from?

For example, if your "stock" options data was instead listed in columns H2:J     then how would you tell the script to pull only data from range H2:J ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay guys I found a solution, anyone visiting this post in the future here you go!!!

*So yes, you can use the script as provided above. However, if you already have other scripts, data validations, and other formatting's going then ,like me, you may actually run into a lot of errors and conflicting issues.*

---

As a workaround here is what I did to get everything to work properly. you will need a total of 3 sheets: a main sheet, a 2nd sheet with your options, and a 3rd sheet to house the pulled data.

1. On the 2nd sheet, be sure to have a column that shows if the item is "in-stock" or "out-of-stock" (I did it as a dropdown menu)

[image]

2. On the 3rd sheet select the cell where you would like the data to show. And use the filter function formula to pull **only the rows from sheet 2 that are equal to "in-stock"**

> **Formula syntax:** =(FILTER (range,  condition1,  [condition2, ...])

**My Formula:**  =FILTER(  sheet2!G3:R5,   sheet2!I3:I5 <> "out-of-stock")

- **sheet2!G3:R5** = the range of rows/columns I want it to pull from.
- **sheet2!I3:I5** = the column I would like it to look for the words "in stock" or "out of stock" in
- **<>"out-of-stock"** = show me the data if a cell in column I3 does not equal "out-of-stock" (meaning, only show in-stock options)

[image]

As you can see the formula will pull/show you all the rows that = "in-stock", anything you have set to "out-of-stock" will not show on the 3rd sheet.

Last part,

3. On the main sheet select the column you would like for your drop down list to show in. Add the data validation **being sure to list from the range on the 3rd sheet** (not sheet 2).

[image]

4. Now you can hide the 3rd sheet as you should no longer need it, unless debugging.

Finally, As you can see now, my main sheet will only show the items in the drop down list that are set to "in-stock", out of stock options are removed from drop down list, unless set back to in-stock. (see how pic3 only shows 2 options in drop list, although pic1 shows that there are 3 options available).

so now basically if I change an item to "out-of-stock" on the 2nd sheet, the item will be removed from drop-down list on the main sheet, AND if I change an item to "in-stock" the item will be added/displayed on the drop list. The 3rd sheet is no longer needed. This solution is perfect if you have multiple users and would only like for them to be able to select an option that is "in-stock"!

Hope this helps someone!!! And thank you to the people of above who gave other possible solutions!!